# Divergence or convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does this converge or diverge?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+\sin^2n}{n}
$$ I tried the divergence test and got infinity. But the graph of the functions shows it converges to zero. Any suggestions? We are not allowed to use delta - epsilon proofs. It is a Calculus II question.

Answer (score 5):

We have that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1+\sin^2n}n\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n
$$
since $\sin^2n\ge0$ and the latter series diverges. Hence, the former series diverges too.